# Select tray with python-cups?

Tags: python, printing, cups

How can I select tray when I send a file to the printer with `python-cups`?

I have a very simple testprogram that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cups
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]

    conn = cups.Connection()
    printers = conn.getPrinters()

    printer_name = printers.keys()[0]
    conn.printFile(printer_name, filename, "TestDoc", {})

    print 'File "%s" sent to printer "%s"' % (filename, printer_name)
```

It sends the given file to the default printer with the *default* paper (tray=1). But I want the doc to be printed on paper from another tray (tray=5). How to I do that?

---

**OR**: Am I doing it the wrong way? Should I go about it some other way to get my doc to the printer? In my final app the doc exist only in memory and not on disk, the only reason for me to write it to disk would be if it was needed by the printing. Note that I would need to switch between trays  for the docs I print.

Comment: Have you managed to figure it out?

Comment: According to this post (https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1264601) you need JDF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Definition_Format) for tray selection. I am unsure if cups supports this.